# Installing packages in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am a new user of Ubuntu. My problem is this. In a CentOS installation guide I came across a command like `yum install libjpeg-devel  libpng-devel` Since I am on Ubuntu I thought this is to be changed as `apt-get install libjpeg-devel  libpng-devel` But it gives and error telling unable to locate package. Please tell me what I did wrong. There are some more commands like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package names are also different. In Debian-based systems like Ubuntu, the package typically has a `-dev` ending as opposed to `-devel`. For example, [`libjpeg-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libjpeg-dev) and [`libpng-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpng-dev). You'll have to manually find each such corresponding package.

Answer (score 5):

**Select software repository like shows below**

`sudo software-properties-gtk`

[image]

[image]

**Install packages**

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev`

Comment: Thank you for support mate. I used the commands and did. :-)

Comment: My pleasure @harsh